# where can I found STM32L4 DSP and standard peripherals library?

Tags: stm32, library, hal-library, nucleo

I want to use standard peripherals library for stm32l476rg(stm32-nucleo). But I could not find it. I dont want to use HAL Library. Do you any suggestion?

Comment: Nothing to do electronic design. Question should be closed.

Comment: @LeonHeller Moved to stackoverflow perhaps?

Comment: @Jeroen3 Only to be closed there as a product request? Why bother?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ST doesn't have a "standard perhiperals library" for L4 as they used to have for other chips, but was discontinued and replaced by STMCube. [STM32CubeL4](http://www.st.com/content/st_com/en/products/embedded-software/mcus-embedded-software/stm32-embedded-software/stm32cube-embedded-software/stm32cubel4.html).

*However*, ST does have Low-Level API. This is new, and is more similar to the old "std periph". These start with: `stm32l4xx_ll_`.

All of which are found in the STMCubeMX tool.

DSP library is found in [CMSIS](https://github.com/ARM-software/CMSIS), not from ST, but from ARM. This is included in ST's library package though.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't exist. ST never wrote a Standard Peripheral Library for the STM32L4 series.

[You're not the first person to wish this existed.](https://www.ipetitions.com/petition/SPLReinstatement) But it's unlikely to happen. You may want to consider using [libopencm3](https://github.com/libopencm3/libopencm3) as an alternative.